# Resource not found exception after running proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I got an app that runs ok, after running proguard the app won't start, I get the following

```
 UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.**/com**Activities.MainActivity}: 
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0 stack =  
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
 ComponentInfo{com.**/com.**.Activities.MainActivity}: 
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Project => Clean => Select your Project => OK

Comment: Clean Project (or) uninstall your app in emulator after run! (or) check your project files are missing or not!

Comment: I am facing similar problem, any idea on how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, it was a long time ago but I think I needed to tell proguard to keep the names of some classes and not obfuscate their namespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you try to access resources which do not exists (usually by mistake) and has nothing to do with MainActivity. The error message is very misleading in this case.